# How to fetch records where the 2nd ID is not present?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, rdbms

There's a table that contains a party ID for which 2 IDs are been associated, ID 1 and ID 2. Both the IDs have their specific ID type code. I want to fetch the party ID (along with ID 1) of those records where ID 2 is missing and only ID 1 is present.

Here is an example of how the table looks;

| PARTY_ID | ID_TYPE_CODE | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 945765545065072501 | 1231 | 9OIWD00002ASTQzIWaS |
| 945765545065072501 | 1446 | 98UE22222U061074536 |

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add a snapshot of your sample data and expected result?

Comment: I am not sure how to differentiate ID 1 and ID 2. Assuming that you would like to see the party ID s with only one ID is present. right>?

Comment: If I get your question right you want to get the party_id numbes for which no id is present. I have not tried it but maybe this helps: `SELECT DISTINCT party_id FROM table WHERE id IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You can count `party_id`'s less than 2 in a subquery then return the associated `party_id`'s and `id`'s:

```
SELECT a.party_id, a.id
FROM
  table_name a, 
  (SELECT party_id
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY party_id
    HAVING COUNT(party_id) < 2) AS b
WHERE a.party_id = b.party_id
```

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d3aab07db1559c647245feec9587587c)